# non-linear classification

Tags: classification

[image: a 2-layer feed-forward neural network that takes in ∈ℝ2 and has two ReLU hidden units]

the hidden units have no offset parameter.[image: The values of the weights in the hidden layer are set such that they result in the 1 and 2 “classifiers" as shown in the (1,2)-space]

The  1  “classifier" with the normal  1=[1121]  is the line given by  1=⋅1=0 . 
Similarly, the  2  “classifier" with the normal  2=[1222]  is the line given by  2=⋅2=0.
The arrows labeled  1  and  2  point in the positive directions of the respective normal vectors.
The regions labeled  I,II,III,IV  are the 4 regions defined by these two lines not including the boundaries.

i need to choose the region(s) in (x_1,x_2) space which are mapped into each of the following regions in (f_1,f_2) space,in the 2-dimensional space of hidden unit activations f(z_1) and f(z_2).

is{(f_1, f_2):f_1 > 0,f_2 > 0} in only  region marked 2.is  f_1 axis lies is in regions marked 1 and 2, and is f_2 axis lies is in regions marked 2 and 3, and is the origin (f_1,f_2)=(0,0) lies in regions marked 1,2,3,4